# Tag для питань, пов'язаних з одруками

Tags: discussion, tags

IMHO, варто вигадати якийсь теґ для питань, що пов'язані з одруками, описками тощо; наприклад: [Утворення слова повітаний](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5090).

"typo", "одрук(и)", "описка(-и)"?..

Answer (score -1):

Застереження:

1. А в нас багато таких питань?
2. Загалом, я не певен, але мені здається, що теґи ставлять ті, хто запитують, і відповідно, вони мають характеризувати саме ту інформацію, яку мають ті, хто запитують, а не ті, хто відповідають. Тобто якщо запитувач питає «чи не одрук це: *ххх*?», то це одне, а якщо запитувач питає «яке значення цього слова: *ххх*?», і навіть гадки не має, що це може бути одрук, і вже відповідачі повідомляють, що це одрук, то це інше — і я не певен, наскільки доречно ставити тег (будь-який) у другому випадку (коли інформація з'явилася після відповіді, а не була частиною запитання).

Але загалом я не проти. Коли Ваш рейтинг зросте до 200, Ви зможете самі створити такий тег і запропонувати редакції до запитань. А якщо хочете швидше (і інші не проти), то я можу створити і зробити редакції запитань (але скажіть, яких ще запитань, щоб я знав, що редагувати).

P.S.: Я б назвав «описка», інші слова як синоніми, якщо треба.